# Is it possible using gets without knowing the length of the array in c?

Tags: c, string, gets

If we want to use gets in c we will do something like:

```
int main(void) {
  char str[100];
  while (gets(str)) {
  printf("%s\n",str); 
 }
}
```

We have to know the length of str first(which is 100) and then use gets. Is it possible using gets without knowing the length of the array in c?

Comment: Number of times this question is asked? : "sorry data can't fit into the variable " :P

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you mean using `gets` safely, no, it's not possible.

**Advice**: don't use `gets`, because without knowing the length first, it may cause buffer overflow. Use [`fgets`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/) instead, or use `gets_s` in C11.

In fact, `gets` has been removed from `stdio.h` since C11. (In C99, it's deprecated)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

Long answer: If you know that the string will be no more than a certain size, you can always allocate a much larger chunk of memory. For example, it's unlikely that a string will be longer than 1k, so you could always simply allocate an array of size 1k. However, this is really inefficient, and also doesn't work if the strings can be arbitrarily long.

Comment: `gets` reads *only* from standard input. Unless you have complete control over what will appear on standard input and can guarantee that no input line will exceed your buffer size, you cannot use `gets` safely. (Think about your cat standing on the space bar for a few minutes.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's safe, but it does at least give you a fairly good margin.

Comment: It's simple: *Never use `gets`*.