# Unable to sort a list of strings alphabetically in C

Tags: c, string, algorithm, sorting

I wrote a program to accept 5 strings from user and then display them sorted alphabetically using bubble-sort algorithm. But, the strings are being displayed in the same order as they were entered. Please tell me what am I doing wrong here.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void sSwap(char *s1, char *s2);

int main(){
    char *sList[5],input[100],*p;
    int i,j;

    puts("Enter 5 strings");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        gets(input);
        sList[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(input)+1);
        strcpy(sList[i],input);
    }

    puts("");

    for(i=3;i>=0;i--){
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
            if(strcmp(sList[j],sList[j+1])>0)
                sSwap(sList[j],sList[j+1]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        puts(sList[i]);
    return 0;
}

void sSwap(char *s1, char *s2){
    char *temp;
    temp = s1;
    s1 = s2;
    s2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: your swap function is incorrect. It does nothing.

Comment: Yeah, looks like a pass-by-reference vs pass-by-value issue.

Comment: Don't use `gets`, it's unsafe, use `fgets` instead.

Comment: Additionally, you might use `strncmp`; always prefer stdlib-implementations to own implementations.

Comment: Swap function worked fine when i set the values at compile time.

Comment: Your sSwap fuction is a NOOP. It needs to take `char **` arguments, not just `char *`.

Comment: @sh94: you are welcome to ignore my advice.

Comment: How is gets unsafe? @Yu Hao

Comment: @sh94 `gets` doesn't have a fixed limit on what it can "get," meaning you're just asking for a buffer overflow.

Comment: @sh94 See here http://stackoverflow.com/a/17737109/1009479

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as you were told, your swap function getting values and swap them by value, meaning that when you leave the function the changes will not be saved and old values will return. try this

```
void sSwap(char **s1, char **s2);

int main(){
    char *sList[5],input[100],*p;
    int i,j;

    puts("Enter 5 strings");
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        gets(input);
        sList[i] = (char *)malloc(strlen(input)+1);
        strcpy(sList[i],input);
    }

    puts("");

    for(i=3;i>=0;i--){
        for(j=0;j<=i;j++){
            if(strcmp(sList[j],sList[j+1])>0)
                sSwap(&sList[j],&sList[j+1]);
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
        puts(sList[i]);
    return 0;
}

void sSwap(char **s1, char **s2){
    char *temp;
    temp = *s1;
    *s1 = *s2;
    *s2 = temp;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't those be `char **`s?

Comment: @DennisMeng you are corect

Comment: Working fine now, but why was the earlier one not working, the array contained addresses of strings, and that was what being passed, so why double pointer?

Comment: @sh94 because a char* is a pointer to [an array of] char[s] (a string), a char ** is a pointer to [an array of] string[s]. you needed to pass the strings by reference to be able to have the modification show outside of your sSwap function

Answer (score 2):

One of your problem is that when you swap two strings, you doesn't check if you have to swap it with the new neighboors of this string.

So I would do a recursive function to solve this. Like if you swap, you call the function (let's say `void sort(char **list, int index)`) :

```
sort(sList, 0) //to start from beginning and check the new order
```

If the strings are equals or in the right order, like :

```
    sort(sList, currentListIndex);
```

So you would have :

```
void sort(char **sList, int index) {
     if (sList[index+1]) {
         if (strcmp(sList[index],sList[index+1]) > 0){
             sSwap(sList, index); // you can swap direclty on the tab
             return sort(sList, 0);
         }
         return sort(sList, index+1);
     }
     return void;
}

sort(sList, 0);
```

It's been a while i didn't do C so maybe pointers are wrong, but it's the idea

Answer (score 1):

The qsort function is in the stdlib.h

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
```

you define the number of elements in array

```
#define n_array sizeof(array)/sizeof(const char *)
```

and the comparison function

```
static int compare (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    return strcmp (*(const char **) a, *(const char **) b);
}
```

and then in main you should use, replacing sSwap

```
qsort (array, n_array, sizeof (const char *), compare);
```

Comment: While true, doesn't really address why the OP's code is wrong.